# spring boot ssl client cert fails with PKIX path building failed error

Tags: spring, tomcat, ssl, spring-boot, client-certificates

I am writing a rest client in spring boot that call secure server API over ssl.

Here is my code:

```
@Value("${secret: not configured}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("${ssl.truststore: not configured}")
    private String sslTrustStore;

    @Value("${url: not configured}")
    private String baseUrl;

    private static final String JAVA_KEYSTORE = "jks";

  public String getUserProfile(String userId) throws Exception {
     KeyStore clientTrustStore = getStore(secret);

            SSLContext sslContext =
                    new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(
                            clientTrustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();

            httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();

            ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                    httpClient);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(getHeaders());

            ResponseEntity<String> response =

                    restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl,
                            HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
            return response.getBody();
        }


        protected KeyStore getStore(String secret) throws
                KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(sslTrustStore);
            final KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance(JAVA_KEYSTORE);
            InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
            try {
                store.load(inputStream, secret.toCharArray());
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            return store;
        }
```

I am able successfully curl with cert to the api server.
I changed the keyStore to PKCS12 and added .p12 file. still same error.

Here is the exception thrown:

```
   org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://myimportant-domain/": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:607)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475)


    at com.company.client.SuperClient.getData(SuperClient.java:94)
    at com.company.ApplicationTests.getDataTest(ApplicationTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:91)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder$TrustManagerDelegate.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextBuilder.java:298)
    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:922)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 68 more
```

Comment: Why are you loading the trust store any special requirement for you to load the store from the code?

Comment: because it is going to change based on environments. dev, qa has diferent than prod

Comment: In that case server does change correct? See my answer below.

Comment: what do you mean by server does change?

Comment: Dev has a different server correct? same for qa, prod etc., ?

Answer (score 0):

If you install the certificate on the server's keystore, the tomcat server will take care of handshaking the ssl cert with the target machine, you dont have to load it in the code every time you invoke a service.

```
<Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="server" keystoreFile="/home/user_name/your_site_name.jks" keystorePass="your_keystore_password" />
```

See the tutorial here : https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-tomcat.htm

**Update:** Spring boot tomcat needs the arguments supplied like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25562938/258741

Comment: I am using embedded tomcat from spring boot

Comment: @brainstorm will you be using embedded tomcat in realtime? If your answer is No, then you should test it out by deploying on real server.

Comment: @brainstorm Updated my answer, see the link at the bottom.

Comment: that is for server. I am using client. it is different.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770280/spring-boot-ssl-client

Comment: @brainstorm did you check the truststore, does it have the installed cert?

Comment: do you mean truststore of java/jre?