# SSL Handshake Exception in SpringBoot RestTemplate PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, resttemplate

I am trying to call an external API that has HTTPS in it. When I invoke it from my Spring Boot Application using Rest Template I get the following error:

> I/O error on POST request for
> "https://url-path": PKIX path building
> failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
> unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested
> exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building
> failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
> unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I generated a self-signed certificate using `keytool`. I tried the following command:

```
sudo keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass <my-password> -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

I was able to generate a file `keystore.jks` which I have placed in my spring boot project at the root.

My code to invoke the external API is:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient
  = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
    .build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory 
  = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);


RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(getHeaders());
ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(URL_TO_CALL, 
        HttpMethod.POST,
        null, Object.class);
Object result = responseEntity.getBody();
```

My `application.properties` file has the following:

```
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=<my-password-given-while-generating-certificate>
server.ssl.trust-store-provider=SUN
```

I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Quick Check: Did you try the verify from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613562/how-can-i-specify-my-keystore-file-with-spring-boot-and-tomcat?

Comment: You created a self signed certificate? Shouldn't you get the public certificate from the service you're connecting and add it to your keystore?